# Affecting parent element of :focus'd element (pure CSS+HTML preferred)

Tags: css, focus, css-selectors

How can I change the background of a parent `<div>` when an `<input>` or `<a>` is :focus'd (or any other dynamic pseudo-class?

Eg

```
<div id="formspace">
<form>
<label for="question">
How do I select #formspace for the case when a child is active?</label>
<input type="text" id="question" name="answer"/></form></div>
```

Comment: Nope: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations (2nd bullet point)

Comment: Thanks all. Just checking since I couldn't seem to come up with any way with pure CSS and html tag movement. I knew javascript could do it; just wanted to keep my hands clean.

Comment: I don't think this question should be considered duplicated to that one. This question is just asking a particular situation but not general question about parent selector. And there _MAY_ be some solution for this situation but not general one, although the general one do _NOT_ have a _solution_.

Comment: The linked question is not a proper duplicate of this question because it does not mention `:focus` -- only parent selectors. There is a new `:focus-within` pseudo selector with some browser support which would satisfy the OP's question here but would not correctly answer the linked "duplicate" question. Can we have this question unmarked as a duplicate or have a more accurate duplicate question linked? @Paulie_D @kapa

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `has()`:

```css
div:has(input:focus), 
div:has(a:focus) {
    background: pink;
}
```

---

Unfortunately css doesn't support parent selectors. :(  
So the only way to do it is to use javascript like the [jQuery parent method][1].

**Update:**
CSS Selectors Level 4 will support parent selectors! http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: [Seems like parent selectors won't make it.](http://css4.rocks/selectors-level-4/subject-of-selector.php)

Answer (score 9):

The only way I can think of is with JavaSCript:

```
function focusLink(isOnFocus)
{
    if (isOnFocus)
      document.getElementById('formspace').className = "<make a focus class name here>";
    else
      document.getElementById('formspace').className = "<default class name here>";
}
```

...

```
<input onFocus="focusLink(true)" onBlur="focusLink(false)">
```

Hope that helps!