# CSS how to style a parent item when a textarea is in focus?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following

```
<div class="comment-wrap">
 <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Whenever the textarea is in focus, I want to style the comment-wrap div.  I've tried:

```
#hallPost-inner + textarea:focus {
    background: red;
}
```

This does not work. Any ideas on how I can style the comment-wrap div whenever the textarea is in focus, meaning the cursor is blinking in the textarea and the user can type?

Thanks

Comment: With jQuery, you could do: `$("textarea").live("focus", function(e) {$(this).closest("comment-wrap").css({background: "red"})});`

Comment: CSS alone won't do it (doesn't support parent selectors).  You'll need a bit of javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212583/affecting-parent-element-of-focusd-element-pure-csshtml-preferred

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what `#hallPost-inner` is, but in general CSS selectors cannot ascend, meaning you would need to have the `textarea:focus` selector, but then would need to style an ancestor element, which cannot be done in css. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child) a good resource, among many others. The link shows how an easy javascript solution can be achieved as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pseudo selector `:focus-within`. Note that any child in focus will effect the parent. If you have more children and just wanna apply when the event hits the `<textarea>`, you will need JS.

[Link for more details.](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/) (css-tricks)

Ex.:

```css
form{
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: gainsboro
}

input{
  text-align: center
}

form:focus-within {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="name">
  <input type="text" placeholder="lastname">
  <input type="button" value="Go!">
</form>
```

**Note**: [not all browsers support `:focus-within`](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Afocus-within)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript and jQuery, you could do:

```
$("textarea").live("focus", function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".comment-wrap").css({
        "background": "red"
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing `.`, and misusing `live()`, and should probably reference `textarea` in some context.

Comment: @davin Thanks, class selector fixed. How is this misusing `.live()`? Using only `.live()` for event listeners only actually creates one universal event listener on the `document` or `window`.

Comment: `live` has some disadvantages/limitations; it cannot properly prevent event propagation, it doesn't support all jquery chained traversals, and doing a regular bind would also only bind one universal event, even if it there were more *references* to it.