# CSS3 - style on focused parent element

Tags: html, css

I know I can set a style on the focused input element like this:

```
input:focus
{ 
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

But is it somehow possible to set a style on a parent element when an input has focus?
e.g.

```
<div class="foo">
      <input type="text />
      Hello
</div>
```

Can I affect the "foo" style when the input has focus here?

edit:
Possible duplicate of [Affecting parent element of :focus'd element (pure CSS+HTML preferred)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212583/affecting-parent-element-of-focusd-element-pure-csshtml-preferred)

However, can someone explain how that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no parent selector in css (yet). http://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/

You can, however, select it with jQuery:

html

```
<div class="parent">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

css

```
.parent {
    /* parent styles */
}
.parent.active {
    /* do stuff when the input is hovered */
}
```

js

```
// listen for a focus event on the input,
//  and then add a class to the parent
$('input').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M64nv/

Comment: Awesome, is there a way to only appy the class to the parent if the parent already contains a specific class? e.g. if parent has class "input-append" and/or "input-prepend" ?

Comment: sure, just add the class as an argument to the .parent() selector, like $(this).parent('input-append').addClass('active');

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no parent selector in CSS, so you cannot trigger style rules on a parent element when one of its descendants is hovered (or based on any child element conditions).  You need to use Javascript for this.